# Can I have more than one {app} variable in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am making an inno setup script. My setup really needs the user to choose to two customized install locations.

But there is only one {app} variable in inno.

Our software is an audio plugin software, the common way in this field is to choose one location for the program and the other location for audio sample/data (which is very large so users usually want to install at a dedicated place for storage and also performance purpose).

Is there any way to get around this condition?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you can't have more than one `{app}`. However, it's really difficult to provide alternatives because your question is very vague and lacking in details. What **exactly** are you trying to do, and why would you need two `{app}` directories? Can you [edit] your question to add more specifics about what you're trying to do? If so, we can probably give you some suggestions about how to get things to work.

Comment: Hi ,ken, thx for tip. I have expanded with some explanation.

Comment: There's an example of getting a custom directory for user data in `CodeDlg.iss` in the `Inno Setup 5\Examples` folder.

Comment: @KenWhite https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other variables (Directory Constants) which you can use, most common ones:

**{app}** - The application directory (user chooses this derectory in Wizard dialog)
You can create subdirectories like {app}\Data

**{win}**
The system's Windows directory.

**{sys}**
The system's System32 directory.

**{pf}**
Program Files.

**{cf}**
Common Files.

And many, many others.

The modern installers store application in one directory - {app} and user's files in every user's custom directory - e.g. **{localappdata}**.

And if this is still not enough you can create your own dialog (wizard page) that contains edit boxes and Browse buttons for selecting directories.

Use `function CreateInputDirPage()` for this purpose.

See manual - Pascal Scripting: CreateInputDirPage for more info.

Comment: Thx for this function name! This is what I am looking for. FYI, a sample code is here http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Prompt_for_an_additional_folder_for_data, and answer from Inno's newsgoups, http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=98603&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#98603

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the included [`CodeDlg.iss`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss) example that shows how to add an extra page for a data directory and hwo to use that value in `[Code]`.

Comment: Or you can use a [`hacky way`](http://pastebin.com/9ghD5h3u) of creating a custom dir input item on *Select Destination Location* wizard page. It produces slightly different browse for folder dialog though. [+1ed]